# C# Find a variable in a file?

Tags: c#, database, variables, editing

I'm making a database and I have a small problem with my system: I can read the whole file only (not the variables) but write variables to my file, but I need to be able to edit the file too. I can edit it but I want to edit the sections by themselves without having to open the whole file for editing / replace the given strings in the whole file only in the sections.

I want to ask the user what section in the file they would change, but my script changes all the strings given to the whole file.

so this is how I want it:

> select file -->select section/line to edit -->input data -->Save data
>   to line

The file looks like this:

```
Name: Kim jr.

Age: 1980/05/20

Gender: Male

Status: Single

Weight: 46.2 Kg

Friends: Unknown

Notes: 
This is a dummy file, used for testing.
```

This is how my code is currently:

```
Console.Clear();

string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Nova_Files\Database"); //slecets the files in the folder

if (fileArray.Length < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("There are no files in the database for deleting");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Here is a list of the files in the database, please select a file to edit.\n");

    foreach (string name in fileArray) //shows the files in the folder.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    userValue = Console.ReadLine();

    string filename = userValue;

    foreach (string x in fileArray)
    {
        if (x.Contains(filename))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(filename + " Was selected for editing");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press anykey to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("The current editing " + filename);
            Console.WriteLine("The File [" + filename + "] Contains This:\n");

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Nova_Files\Database\" + filename);

            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to edit?");
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            string needOfEdit = userValue;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What will you replace " + needOfEdit + " With?");
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            string replacement = userValue;

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Nova_Files\Database\" + filename, File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Nova_Files\Database\" + filename).Replace(needOfEdit, replacement));
            text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Nova_Files\Database\" + filename);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind bringing in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly, you can get what you are looking for via Random File access:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711474(v=vs.71).aspx

The file operations described in the MSDN link (such as `FileOpen`) are in the `FileSystem` class after you reference the assembly  in C#.  --  i.e. `FileSystem.FileOpen()`

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is not possible. Files are sequential chunks of `inode` saved in a disk. It is  a huge `linked list` like structure. You can't find the next node unless you fetch and check the previous node.

So which means you can't just replace a special location in a file. You have to read the file up to that position at least once to find that position.

In your case, I think the best option is -

1. Keep an object with all the properties that can be updated.
2. Take input and update the property of that object
3. Then finally when done, write that object data inside the file. So whatever change is done, it is automatically reflected in the file..

This way you can keep track of changed items.

But in any way you have to write the full file each time you change something in the middle.

Comment: Okay thanks so how would i do that? i have no idea right now